# When does GetByteArrayElements return null?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI/NDK to tie in some C++ libraries with an Android app.  One of the Java methods uses a byte array, so I need to call GetByteArrayElements in the JNI bindings.  In what cases does GetByteArrayElements return NULL?  Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) simply states:

`Returns a pointer to the array elements, or NULL if the operation fails.`

What cases can cause the operation to fail and return NULL?

Answer (score 1):

It returns NULL [if the operation fails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314), and not otherwise, including your case of an empty array.

Comment: Rephrased the question slightly, because, "Are there cases where it can return null?" was looking for what those cases are, not just a simple, "Yep." Thought that would be obvious to any reader, but I guess not.